# WP-PostRatings - how to make rating show up?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-postratings

I have [Boldy](http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/doc/) theme on a 3.2.1 instance of Wordpress.

I have installed the plugin [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/installation/).

I want it to show up on my individual posts when posts are viewed individually on a page.

- I installed and activated the plugin.
- I added
  `if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>`
  within my *single.php* file, as [shown in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yaJVu4DX).

However, nothing is happening with my blog posts when [viewed as single pages](http://www.dekho.com.au/sort-on-multiple-columns-in-results).

Have I put the code in the wrong place/file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few things you can check

1. the code is within the loop
2. the plugin is activated
3. check plugin option page and select a rating type
4. check page source code and see what is being generated.
5. if all ok. your css is not blocking any rating star tag.
6. de-activate, uninstall, delete and re-install the plugin

Comment: 1. yes, right under  
2. yes  
3. Done - tried others
4. No mention of ratings where id expect it (Above post title)
5. Do not think so...
6. Tried and same issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok some more thoughts.
do you have

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

in your theme's footer.php

do you have any lightbox plugin installed?

deactivate all plugins except rating, then does it work?